# How do I group values by row in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, pivot-table

I am new to SSRS and need some help.

I am using a Matrix to Pivot my data.

Dataset looks like this:

```
TEST   TOOLID
-----  ------
TEST1  123
TEST1  234
TEST2  456
```

What I currently have is this:

```
              TEST1   TEST2
TOOL ID       123     N/A
TOOL ID       234     N/A
TOOL ID       N/A     456
```

The output I am looking for is (NULLS should be converted to N/A):

```
              TEST1   TEST2
TOOL ID 1     123     456
TOOL ID 2     234     N/A
```

Thanks

jlimited

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Details in lower left of view pane under 'Row Groups'
2. Right Click>Add Group>Parent Group
3. Choose your item you want to group by, include header is the standard behavior(check box to select).  Hit okay.

You are now grouping your columns and you should see a bit more geometric ( in the gray space before the rows showing they are grouped accordingly now.